# Run-time Error - Method 'Apply" of Object 'Sort' failed

Tags: vba, excel

Currently received the following error:

> Run-time Error - Method 'Apply" of Object 'Sort' failed

Based on code below:

```
'In the MTD Crystal Reports workbook that has the new data, sort the data
Range("A2:AF65536").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A65536" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:AF65536")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

- Debugger brings me to ".Apply"
- I've confirmed that the sort rows/columns fall within the .SetRange

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Add `.` before `Range("A2:AF65536")` --> `.SetRange .Range("A2:AF65536")`

Comment: @BruceWayne - I am pretty sure that your suggestion will fail since the parent in this case is the `.Sort` method itself, which does not hold a direct `Range` object as a child.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - D'oh, I didn't catch that. Good call :thumbsup:

Answer (score 1):

Silly error, but I am posting this as a solution as it may effect others in the future.

The code that I posted was sufficient to run, error was due to the fact that I had my Excel Options > Formula > Workbook Calculation "MANUAL"

When I changed Workbook Calculation to "Automatic", the Sort issue was corrected.

Comment: Ha, nice find. I'll have to keep this in mind, because I've hit the same issue before. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 1):

Having hidden rows on the sheet being sorted will also cause this error.

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not apply to your particular problem but I am posting it here for the benefit of anybody searching this error.

Referencing the Sort member beneath a ListObject.AutoFilter object will also cause this error. Here was my code:

```
Selection.ListObject.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add 'etc.
...
Selection.ListObject.AutoFilter.Sort.Header = xlYes 'etc.
...
Selection.ListObject.AutoFilter.Sort.Apply 'error raised here.
```

I fixed my problem by instead referencing the Sort member directly from the ListObject object:

```
Selection.ListObject.Sort.Sortfields.Add 'etc.
...
Selection.ListObject.Sort.Header = xlYes 'etc.
...
Selection.ListObject.Sort.Apply 'method executed successfully.
```

Hope I helped.